# Hair show face's normals

Tags: modifiers, particles, hair

my hair simulation shows what appears to be triangles over the surface which are, from what i assume, the face's mesh showing through the hair for some reason.
[image]

This is still visible with subdivision modifier, only way i can make them disappear is if i subdivide the actual mesh a couple times... which is not really performance friendly when animating stuff. What's the best way to not make these faces/edges "visible" ?

Comment: Maybe the edges are set to sharp, if it is the case, try select them all and hit CTRL + E -> clear sharp.

Answer (score 1):

The subdivision modifier needs to be placed after the particle emitter in the modifier stack. Place it before, using the up arrow, and it should be fine:

[image: modifier stack]

**Edit**: Actually the object faces still influence the emitter even with a subsurface modifier.
But setting the object shading to smooth should do the trick:

[image: setting smooth shading]

Comment: uhh no, the problem is still present, thats also uh- how i had it set up on the pic i sent

Comment: @Zophiekat Right, my bad. Edited my answer, hope this works

Comment: @Zophiekat oh, and if it doesn't work (the sphere in your pic already looks pretty smooth), could you attach the blend file?

Comment: its already set to shaded smooth

Answer (score 1):

1. use shade smoothing
2. use interpolated hair children (you can use Virtual parents on top of it + a bit of randomness)
   [image]
3. use subdiv modifier but disable it in viewport for smoother animations
   [image]